# RGB values to Color.value

Tags: java, netbeans, rgb

I'm making a color pick program.
I get color value from user with JColorChooser:
JColorChooser jc = new JColorChooser();
myColor = jc.showDialog(null, "Choose background color", Color.yellow);

I also have a label and text of this label is selected color value( but I want it to be represented like: red, yellow, green.....). But i can get  only RGB values of selected color- something like this (java.awt.Color[r=102,g=0,b=102]).
Is there a way yo convert it to string of values like "green", or "yellow".....?
But without making my own code with declared values?

Comment: A computer isn't intelligent. The only way to do this is to create your own code with declared values for a specified range of color (it's easier with HSL colors).

Comment: You mean it can be done with HSL?

Comment: No, it's easier to create your own code and work with colors in HSL space. Just assign a color name for to each range of hue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just few lines of code(depending of your sys...). 
Maybe set colors this way http://hslpicker.com/#26d9c1
with hsl(172, 70%, 50%, 1), then, (if you make a code that just gives user colors options where only 1st values can be changed (variable, 70%,50%,1), colors available after this editing should left enough colors for human eye.
Than just read variable and set something with if for example:

`if(40 <= variable =< 70) {
System.out.print("yellow");
}`